# std::sort by unary mapping

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, std

The C++ standard library offers to pass a Comparator to `std::sort`. However, I have many cases in my code where I want to sort a list of `T` objects by a function `f`. A comparator like this would be a valid option:

```
bool compare(const T& a, const T& b) {
  return f(a) < f(b);
}
```

This is not optimal though. `f` is slow to evaluate but will return the same value for every call with the same `T` object. So what I would rather do is compute `f` once for every object in the range and then use those results to sort them.

My goal is to write this function (which I have not been able to do):

```
template <typename IterT, typename Transformation>
void sort(IterT left, IterT right, Transformation f) { /* ? */ }
```

Such that after this call, `f(*iter) <= f(*std::next(iter))` for all `iter` in the sequence `left` to `right`.

Furthermore, the function should satisfy these requirements:

- Does not allocate any additional objects of type `T`.
- Evaluates `f` exactly `std::distance(left, right)` many times.
- Maintains the overall complexity of O(n log n).
- Should be implemented in terms of std::sort. Of course I could solve this problem by implementing my own merge sort but that is something I would like to avoid.

(C++11 is preferred; C++14 is also ok)

Comment: Why not store the result of `f(a)` inside object `a` and only compute it when  the state of the object changes?

Comment: You could use "memoization" to cache the results of `f` - e.g. using an `unordered_map`. It complicates things if you can't copy objects of type `T` to use as the map keys - is there some subset of the data in `T` that `f` uses? Alternatively, can you sort an array of pointers to the real objects?

Comment: Does `f(*iter)` depend only of `*iter` or on `iter`?

Comment: You could create a range of values `f(a)` for all `a` and also a range of indices, and then sort the indices according to the precomputed values of `f`. You'd then have the permutation of your original range that puts it in sorted order, so you just need to apply that permutation.

Comment: @RichardCritten That would be a possibility but a really ugly one. `f`is not related to the class directly and only relevant in some use cases; so I would have some member in the class that is never used in many code pieces. Besides that, I would have to manually call something like "updateF" everytime I change the object.

Comment: @AlanStokes I thought about the map as well, but copying the objects is too expensive to do it that liberally. How would your proposal with the array of points help? In the end, I want to sort the sequence of iterators.

Comment: @KerrekSB f only depends on the object of type T, i.e. `*iter`. I understand your solution with the ranges. It definitely works and I could use that, thanks. I will still leave the the question open for a bit for possible other ideas.

Comment: @Kerrek's suggestion is better than mine anyway.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Not necessarily. A memoized `f` has advantages, too; it simplifies the logic and can potentially be reused across a broader scope. It depends on how suitable `T` is for memoization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what you want is a C++ implementation of a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). I don't have a simple solution in a few lines of code, but I did implement a [Schwartzian transform utility](https://github.com/Morwenn/cpp-sort/wiki/Sorter-adapters#schwartz_adapter) in a C++14 library of mine. Unfortunately it relies on proxy iterators, which aren't handled by `std::sort` (at least not until the Ranges TS), but you can use any other sorter from the library instead. Here is how you could write the `sort` function mentioned in your question:

```
#include <cpp-sort/adapters/schwartz_adapter.h>
#include <cpp-sort/sorters/default_sorter.h>

template <typename IterT, typename Transformation>
void sort(IterT left, IterT right, Transformation f)
{
    using sorter = cppsort::schwartz_adapter<cppsort::default_sorter>;
    sorter{}(left, right, f);
}
```

When called this way, the sorter will cross `[left, right)` and create `std::distance(left, right)` pairs associating an iterator `it` to `f(*it)`. Then it will use the passed sorter (`default_sorter` in the example above, which is a [pattern-defeating quicksort](https://github.com/orlp/pdqsort) at the time of writing) to sort the collection of pairs. [Proxy iterators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0022r0.html) are used under the hood so that elements of the original collection are swapped whenever pairs are swapped.

I wouldn't say it's quite simple, but it should solve your problem. If you don't want to rely on an external library, you can still take inspiration from [the soure code](https://github.com/Morwenn/cpp-sort/blob/master/include/cpp-sort/adapters/schwartz_adapter.h). It is under a permissive license, so you can do pretty much whatever you want to with it if you need to use elements from it.

Anyway, it looks like it mostly satifies your requirements:

- It doesn't allocate additional instances of `T` (unless `f` returns a new instance of `T` since it stores the return value of `f`).
- It applies `f` exactly `std::distance(left, right)` prior to the actual sorting.
- It maintains the overall complexity of O(n log n) if used with an O(n log n) sorter.
- This latest bullet is the only one not being satisfied: it doesn't use `std::sort` because `std::sort` isn't smart enough as of today, but it can use equivalent algorithms without you having to write your own.

Comment: Thanks, also for pointing out the term Schwartzian transform. There is another proposed solution in the comments to my question which uses std::sort but depending on the use case, yours might be more suitable, so I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @AndreasT That's true, and that's probably a simpler solution per se (and especially usable since RaymondChen wrote an excellent series of articles to perform this kind of sort). The indices-based solution probably takes more time since it performs a sort *then* a permutation, but I would time things before asserting that :p

Comment: @Morwenn The index-based version is faster if swapping an object is more expensive than swapping integers, because the sort swaps integers O(n log n) times, then swaps objects n times. Whereas a Schwartzian transform swaps objects O(n log n) times.

Comment: @RaymondChen By the way, I also have an `indirect_adapter` in my sorting library which performs an iterator-based indirect sort. I wanted to try your index-based algorithm and see whether it performs better (I guess it does). However I couldn't find any license notice on your blog, and thus couldn't tell whether it was possible to reuse your algorithm in my MIT-licensed library if it happened to perform better.

Comment: I'll see what I can do about the blog code. I'll try to get it under MIT. (I think it defaults to MSPL.)

Comment: @Thanks. That's very kind of you :)

Comment: @RaymondChen Any news on the licensing topic?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to `std::sort` just write a comparator that caches the value of your function for every instance of `T`.

Example:

```
struct Foo {
    int value;
};

// Replace with your CPU time intensive f() function
int evaluate(const Foo& foo) {
    std::cout << "Evaluating complex function on an instance of Foo..." << std::endl;
    return foo.value;
}

bool compare(const Foo& left, const Foo& right) {
    static std::unordered_map<Foo, int> cache;
    auto leftIt = cache.find(left);
    auto rightIt = cache.find(right);
    if (leftIt == cache.end())
        leftIt = cache.emplace(left, evaluate(left)).first;
    if (rightIt == cache.end())
        rightIt = cache.emplace(right, evaluate(right)).first;
    return (*leftIt).second < (*rightIt).second;
}
```

You can find a complete example here: https://gist.github.com/PandarinDev/ee75b095c4cc256a88496f1985bf57ba

This way `evaluate(const Foo&);` (`f(T)` in your case) will only be ran N times, where `N = the number of unique instances of Foo`.

**Edit:** As mentioned below in the comments, if the copy of `T` instances into the map is a problem to you, you can use a unique identifier - such as the address of your object - as a key instead of the object itself.

Comment: This causes every object in the sequence to be copied, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @AndreasT - if the problem is the copy of `Foo` objects in the `cache` map, you can use a `cache` map with pointers to `Foo` keys: `static std::unordered_map<Foo*, int> cache;`; the search become `auto leftIt = cache.find(&left); auto rightIt = cache.find(&right);`; the insertions `cache.emplace(&left, evaluate(left)).first;` and `cache.emplace(&right, evaluate(right)).first;`

Comment: Yes, it will copy the `T` objects into the map (if not already present). If you don't want to copy the objects into the map just use a unique identifier for each instance as a key.

Comment: Caching the pointers won't work because the sort algorithm is going to move object around, which changes their pointers.

Comment: @RaymondChen:  Didn't you cover this recently on your blog?  Oh yeah, the series starts here:  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170102-00/?p=95095